# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/

Tags: django, account

Django beginner. the project is aboud a really basic food delivery app.

I have extended the User Model using a One-to-One link as specified [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone), in order to include a 'city' field when a new user tries to register.

The problem is that when I create a superuser in the python shell, and try to access that account from 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/ and hit login, the following page is returned:

[image]

As far as I can tell, this is due to the fact that every User/Superuser has to be linked to one Customer object.

How can I avoid this? Could a solution be to overwrite the superuser class by specifying that that field 'city' is not needed? If yes, how can I do that? If not, what is the best practice in this case?

here is accounts/model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from city.models import City
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_customer_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Customer.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_customer_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.customer.save()
```

If you need any other code to be uploaded, please let me know that, because the only code involved I can think of is the one I have posted.

Thanks in advance